# Jquery Script not working properly on IE7

Tags: jquery, hover, internet-explorer-7, compatibility

I have this script for a floor plan that changes individual apartment images on hover so they display a different color. It works on every single browser except IE7. On IE7 when hovered over, the images change but not to the correct one but to the one on another floor. I did not write the script myself and I am just in charge of debugging it and have no idea what parts of it don't work correctly in IE7. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // add links to sidebar
    $('#secondary-nav').append('<li id="f2" class="floor">Floor 2</li>');
    $('#secondary-nav').append('<li id="f3" class="floor">Floor 3</li>');
    $('#secondary-nav').append('<li id="f4" class="floor">Floor 4</li>');
    $('#secondary-nav').append('<li id="f5" class="floor">Floor 5</li>');
    $('#secondary-nav').append('<li id="f6" class="floor">Floor 6</li>');
    $('#secondary-nav').append('<li id="f7" class="floor">Floor 7</li>');

    // display floor
    $('#secondary-nav li').click(function(){
        var floor = $(this).attr('id').replace('f','');
        $('#frame').fadeOut(200);
        $('#secondary-nav li').removeClass('current');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#floors li#f'+floor).addClass('current');
            $('.units').css('display','none');
            $('#frame').css('background-image','url(floorplans/img/selectors/floorplates-bg/'+floor+'.png)');
            $('#frame').fadeIn(200);
            $('#floor'+floor).fadeIn(200);
        }, 500);
    });

    // highlight on mouseover
    $(".units div").hover(function(){$('img',this).stop().animate({opacity:0},200);}, 
                          function(){$('img',this).stop().animate({opacity:1},200);});

    // display floorplan
    $('.units div').each(function(i){
        var floor = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace('floor','');
        var unit = floor + $(this).attr('class').replace('u','');
        var details = $('a',this).attr('title');
        var group = $('a',this).attr('class').replace('i','');
        $(this).click(function(){
            $('#details .info h1').html('Unit '+unit);
            $('#details .info h2').html(details);
            $('#details .info a').attr('href','floorplans/downloads/'+group+'.pdf');
            $('#details .floorplate img').attr('src','floorplans/img/floorplans/floorplates/Unit-'+unit+'.png');
            $('#details .floorplan img').attr('src','floorplans/img/floorplans/'+group+'.png');
        });
        $(this).fancybox({'href':'#details'});
    });

});
```

Comment: You know, you can re-use some of those selectors, right? and you can append more than one html node per use of .append?

Comment: The only thing i see that raises a flag compatibility-wise is the use of opacity. For opacity to work in older versions of IE, several things have to be in-place in your css. For example, the element must have a layout. Setting it's position to relative, applying zoom, or giving it display: inline-block are all ways of accomplishing that.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks Kevin B! I did not write the script so I was just looking at fixing the one thing I needed and was not really trying to optimize the script. Now that you mention that I will change that part.

Comment: This is the page I am working on: http://www.southstarlofts.com/loft-floorplans/